# glGetTexImage() is just giving me black

Tags: opengl, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to get the contents of a`GL_TEXTURE_2D` into a RGBA byte array.

Here's my code:

```
void save(void* textureHandle, int width, int height){
    GLubyte *pixels = new GLubyte[width * height * 4];
    GLuint gltex = (GLuint)(size_t)(textureHandle);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, gltex);
    glGetTexImage(GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                  0,
                  GL_RGBA,
                  GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                  pixels);
    // Do fun stuff with pixels
}
```

`textureHandle` is passed in by Unity, which says this about it: "On OpenGL-like devices the GL texture "name" is returned; cast the pointer to integer type to get it".

In my head, following this code block `pixels` should be filled with the `[r1, g1, b1, a1, r2, ...]` values that represent the texture passed in. However, the entire array is just `[0,0,0,0...]`. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: Use `glActiveTexture(someTextureUnit)` before glGetTexImage

Comment: also is the texture valid 2D RGBA texture? also if the texture is a render target what gfx hw you got (Intel has known problems with rendering to texture so maybe the texture is really black)?

Comment: @Ripi2: The value of `gltex` does not appear to align with any of the value of `GL_TEXTUREi`. Is there a specific way to set the contents of gltex to one of the `GL_TEXTURE` locations?

@Rabbid76: Relatively confident I do. I'm calling the function in a native plugin to unity, and the function call is send by `GL.IssuePluginEvent`, which makes sure that the code is running on the render loop.

Comment: Found this [Unity texture read sample](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RenderTexture-active.html)

Comment: The entire point of my project is to avoid that function. It's way too slow, and I want this to run on every frame.